# PHP symfony4: Dependency injection inside KernelTestCase for command

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phpunit, symfony4

Hello I'm trying to create a unit-test for a symfony4 console command but I can't inject the dependencies correctly. I'm very new to symfony4 so maybe this is a basic question for you guys.

My unit test looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Command;

use App\Command\ExecuteSalesTaskCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use App\Repository\TaskRepository;

class ExeculteSalesTaskCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param TaskRepository  $taskRepository
     */
    public function testExecute(LoggerInterface $logger, TaskRepository $taskRepository)
    {
        $kernel      = self::bootKernel();
        $application = new Application($kernel);

        $application->add(new ExecuteSalesTaskCommand($logger,$taskRepository));

        # UPDATED
        $logger         = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $taskRepository = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get(TaskRepository::class);

        $command       = $application->find('app:execute-sales-task');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(
            [
                'command'  => $command->getName(),
            ]
        );

        // the output of the command in the console
        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertContains('Execute sales resulted: ', $output);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get injection errors like this:

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Tests\Command\ExeculteSalesTaskCommandTest::testExecute(), 0
>   passed and exactly 2 expected

UPDATE:
When I fetch the dependencies out of the container I get this kind of error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) App\Tests\Command\ExeculteSalesTaskCommandTest::testExecute
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   The "Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" service or alias has been removed or
>   inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it
>   public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency
>   injection instead.

How can I inject the necessary dependencies correctly, so I can create an instance of the ExecuteSalesTaskCommand?

Comment: Check the [example](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/tests-clear-data#booting-the-container), `self::bootKernel()` allows you to get services from container `self::$kernel->getContainer()->get()`

Comment: I've updated my question. The getContainer()->get solution is not working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found out that the issue was that I tried to load the dependencies manually. Use the autowiring instead like this:

```
public function testExecute()
{
    $dotenv = new Dotenv();
    $dotenv->load(__DIR__.'/.env.test');

    $kernel      = self::bootKernel();
    $application = new Application($kernel);

    $executeSalesCommand = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get(
        'console.command.public_alias.App\Command\ExecuteSalesTaskCommand'
    );

    $application->add($executeSalesCommand);

    $command       = $application->find('app:execute-sales-task');
    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute(
        [
            'command' => $command->getName(),
        ]
    );

    // the output of the command in the console
    $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();

    // do your asserting stuff
}
```

You need to get the command itself from the kernel container. Now it works.

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for exact the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was also encountered similar issue. But following worked for me. I don't think you need to add command to the application and again to find it? Please find following solution. It might help others.

```
<?php
// BaseCommandTester.php
/**
 * This is basis for the writing tests, that will cover commands
 *
 */
namespace App\Tests\Base;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

class BaseCommandTester extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $application;

    /**
     * to set test environment and initiate application kernel
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        /**
         * get test env
         */
        $dotenv = new Dotenv();
        $dotenv->load('/var/www/.env.test');

        /**
         * boot kernel
         */
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->application = new Application($kernel);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->application;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $application
     */
    public function setApplication($application)
    {
        $this->application = $application;
    }

}
```

Test Case

```
// FeedUpdaterCommandTest.php
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Command;

use App\Tests\Base\BaseCommandTester;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class FeedUpdaterCommandTest extends BaseCommandTester
{
    /**
     * test to update all feeds
     */
    public function testExecuteUpdateAll() {
        /**
         * init command tester and executre
         */
        $commandName = 'app:feedUpdater';
        $expectedResult = '[OK] Update Success Feed Type : All';

        $command = $this->getApplication()->find($commandName);
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(array(
            'command' => $command->getName()
        ));

        /**
         * get result and compare output
         */
        $result = trim($commandTester->getDisplay());
        $this->assertEquals($result, $expectedResult);
    }
}
```

Result of Test run

```
#Run tests
root@xxx:/var/www# bin/phpunit tests/Command
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing tests/Command
2018-11-28T07:47:39+00:00 [alert] Successful update of popularProducts Feeds!
2018-11-28T07:47:39+00:00 [alert] Successful update of topVouchers Feeds!
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.44 seconds, Memory: 12.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

I am using following Sf4 version

```
 -------------------- --------------------------------------
  Symfony
 -------------------- --------------------------------------
  Version              4.1.7
```

Service Defination and its by default private

```
#config/services.yml
    App\Service\FeedGenerator:
        arguments:
            $feeds: '%feed_generator%'
```

I don't think you need to autowire again.